# How to check WSL 2 build version?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

The `wsl --update` gives us a way to update it to get new features and fixes as usual in other software.

But is there any way to check the current build version of it to know whether I need to update it or not?

Note: Here I don't mean the distinction between the older WSL and WSL 2 but the current build version of WSL 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the version of your currently installed WSL2 with a following command in CMD/Powershell:

`wsl --version`

It should looks like this:

```
C:\Users\user>wsl --version
WSL version: 1.0.3.0
Kernel version: 5.15.79.1
WSLg version: 1.0.47
MSRDC version: 1.2.3575
Direct3D version: 1.606.4
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.19045.2486
```

Comment: Notice that `wsl --version` does not work on the earlier WSL 2 versions, I think WSL v1.0.0 is the first version supporting that command. For others the best you can get is `wsl --status`, see also https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/1649